# ¿Como puedo comprobar si el navegador almacena cache despues de implementar las directivas no-cache en HTML?

Tags: html, navegador-web

como puedo comprobar si el navegador está o no almacenando caché después de implementar las directivas no-cache en HTML:

[image: Directivas]

Comment: El código [debe ir en texto y no en imagen](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/ser%c3%ada-posible-a%c3%b1adir-al-art%c3%adculo-c%c3%b3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta-indicacion/4433#4433). En cuanto tu cabecera `cache-control`, no tiene sentido añadir `no-cache` y `must-revalidate` si vas a usar [`no-store`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#prevenci%C3%B3n_del_almacenamiento_2). Para saber si el recurso se almacenó o no debes inspeccionar el almacenamiento del navegador. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias @MauricioContreras una duda ¿entonces no-cache y must-revalidate están sobrando y con no-store debería de bastar?